# Error when starting Spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

[image]Someone please help me, from last 2 days i am trying to set up spark and python environment.
unfortunately couldn't able to do so.

Error:-

```
Spark-shell
failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.object in compiler mirror not found
```

These are path i set up:

```
Anaconda root: C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
Python: C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
c:\spark
```

Environment Variable:

```
Name: HADOOP_HOME
value: C:\Winutils


JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1


SPARK_HOME
C:\SPARK
```

i have not installed scala yet.

may someone please help me to do set up.

**is there any way to fix the above error or call pyspark using Jupyter notebook from Anaconda**

Comment: How did you install Spark?

Comment: @desertnaut: Thanks. i downloaded the file, and configure the env variable, and trying to call it through cmd. eg:- spark-shell. am i missing something ?

Comment: is there any way to fix the above error or call pyspark using Jupyter notebook from Anaconda.

Comment: May someone please suggest how to install pyspark in Anaconda. Thanks

Comment: Remove Java 9 and install Java 8 and try it out.